# `use` keyword doesn't work with curry form?

Tags: f#

```
let make f =
  printfn "1"
  use file = File.CreateText("abc.txt")
  let v = f file
  printfn "2"
  v

let f (x: StreamWriter) (y:int) = 
  printfn "3"
  x.WriteLine("{0}", y)

let a = make f

> 1
> 2
> val a : (int -> unit)

a 8

System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
```

When compiling this doesn't give me any error or warning, but in the runtime it triggers such error.

Do I have to use the full version `let make f y = ...` to avoid the curried form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `use` keyword ensures that the `Dispose` method is called at the end of the lexical scope. This means that it calls it when a value is returned from your `make` function. The problem is that in your case, the returned value is a *function* that is called later.

In other words, what you're writing could be also seen as:

```
let make f =
  printfn "1"
  use file = File.CreateText("abc.txt")
  printfn "2"
  (fun y -> f file y)
```

Here, you can see why this does not work. If you want to call the function `f` with all arguments before the file is disposed of, you need to write something like this:

```
let make f y =
  printfn "1"
  use file = File.CreateText("abc.txt")
  let v = f file y
  printfn "2"
  v
```